# How to crawl and scrape one set of data from multiple linked pages with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

What I am trying to do is to scrape company information (thisisavailable.eu.pn/company.html) and add to the board dict all the board members with their respective data from separate pages.

So ideally the data that I get back from sample pages would be:

```json
{
    "company": "Mycompany Ltd",
    "code": "3241234",
    "phone": "2323232",
    "email": "info@mycompany.com",
    "board": {
        "1": {
            "name": "Margaret Sawfish",
            "code": "9999999999"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "Ralph Pike",
            "code": "222222222"
        }
    }
}
```

I have searched Google and SO (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061702/scrapy-crawl-and-scrape-a-website) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870694/how-to-collect-data-from-multiple-pages-into-single-data-structure-with-scrapy) and [Scrapy docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-meta) etc) but have not been able to find a solution for problem exactly like this.

What I have been able to cobble together:

items.py:

```
import scrapy
class company_item(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    code = scrapy.Field()
    board = scrapy.Field()
    phone = scrapy.Field()
    email = scrapy.Field()
    pass

class person_item(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    code = scrapy.Field()    
    pass
```

spiders/example.py:

```
import scrapy
from try.items import company_item,person_item

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    #allowed_domains = ["http://thisisavailable.eu.pn"]
    start_urls = ['http://thisisavailable.eu.pn/company.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        if response.xpath("//table[@id='company']"):
            yield self.parse_company(response)
            pass
        elif response.xpath("//table[@id='person']"):
            yield self.parse_person(response)
            pass        
        pass

    def parse_company(self, response):
        Company = company_item()
        Company['name'] = response.xpath("//table[@id='company']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()").extract_first()
        Company['code'] = response.xpath("//table[@id='company']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()").extract_first()
        board = []
         
        for person_row in response.xpath("//table[@id='board']/tbody/tr/td[1]"):
            Person = person_item()
            Person['name'] = person_row.xpath("a/text()").extract()
            print (person_row.xpath("a/@href").extract_first())
            request = scrapy.Request('http://thisisavailable.eu.pn/'+person_row.xpath("a/@href").extract_first(), callback=self.parse_person)
            request.meta['Person'] = Person
            return request          
            board.append(Person)

        Company['board'] = board
        return Company      

    def parse_person(self, response):       
        print('PERSON!!!!!!!!!!!')
        print (response.meta)
        Person = response.meta['Person']
        Person['name'] = response.xpath("//table[@id='person']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()").extract_first()
        Person['code'] = response.xpath("//table[@id='person']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()").extract_first()
        yield Person
```

UPDATE:
As Rafael noticed, initial problem was with allowed_domains being wrong - I commented it out for the time being and now when I run it, I get (added *'s to URLs due to low rep):

> > scrapy crawl example 2017-03-07 09:41:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.2 started (bot: proov) 2017-03-07 09:41:12
> > [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE':
> > 'proov.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['proov.spiders'],
> > 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'proov'} 2017-03-07 09:41:12
> > [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
> > ['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
> > 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
> > 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats'] 2017-03-07 09:41:13
> > [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
> > ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats'] 2017-03-07
> > 09:41:13 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
> > ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
> > 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware'] 2017-03-07 09:41:13
> > [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: [] 2017-03-07
> > 09:41:13 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2017-03-07 09:41:13
> > [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),
> > scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2017-03-07 09:41:13
> > [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on
> > 127.0.0.1:6023 2017-03-07 09:41:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://*thisisavailable.eu.pn/robots.txt> (referer: None)
> > 2017-03-07 09:41:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> > http://*thisisavailable.eu.pn/scrapy/company.html> (referer: None)
> > person.html person2.html 2017-03-07 09:41:15 [scrapy.core.engine]
> > DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [http://thisisavailable.eu.pn/person2.html>](http://thisisavailable.eu.pn/person2.html%3E)
> > (referer: http://*thisisavailable.eu.pn/company.html) PERSON!!!!!!!!!!!
> > 2017-03-07 09:41:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200
> > http://*thisisavailable.eu.pn/person2.html> {'code': u'222222222',
> > 'name': u'Kaspar K\xe4nnuotsa'} 2017-03-07 09:41:15
> > [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished) 2017-03-07
> > 09:41:15 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
> > {'downloader/request_bytes': 936,  'downloader/request_count': 3,
> > 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
> > 'downloader/response_bytes': 1476,  'downloader/response_count': 3,
> > 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
> > 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,  'finish_reason':
> > 'finished',  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 7, 7, 41, 15,
> > 571000),  'item_scraped_count': 1,  'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
> > 'log_count/INFO': 7,  'request_depth_max': 1,
> > 'response_received_count': 3,  'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
> > 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,  'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
> > 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017,
> > 3, 7, 7, 41, 13, 404000)} 2017-03-07 09:41:15 [scrapy.core.engine]
> > INFO: Spider closed (finished)

and if run with "-o file.json", file content is:

> [ {"code": "222222222", "name": "Ralph Pike"} ]

---

So a bit further, but I am still at loss how to make it work.

Can somebody help me make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't related to having multiple items, even though it will be in the future.

You problem is explained in the output

> [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'kidplay-wingsuit.c9users.io': http://thisisavailable.eu.pn/scrapy/person2.html> 2017-03-06 10:44:33

It means that is going to a domain outside of your allowed_domains list.

Your allowed domains is wrong. It should be

```
allowed_domains = ["thisisavailable.eu.pn"]
```

Note:

Instead of using a different item for `Person` just use it as a field in `Company` and assign a `dict` or `list` to it while scraping